# Documentation for inlining of built-ins?

Tags: perl

I ran into a situation where I can't inhibit warnings in an intuitive way because perl is in-lining a call to a built-in function. e.g.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    no warnings 'substr';      # no effect
    foo(substr('123', 4, 6));  # out of range but shouldn't emit a warning
}

sub foo {
    my $s = shift;  # warning reported here
    # do something
}
```

Running this code results in

```
substr outside of string at c:\temp\foo.pl line 10.
```

In order to inhibit the warning I have to move the `no warnings 'substr'` inside the function.

```
sub foo {
    no warnings 'substr'; # works here, but there's no call to substr
    my $s = shift;        # no warnings here
    # do something
}
```

I can see that the call to `substr` is being inlined by passing the code through `perl -MO=Terse`

```
LISTOP (0x27dcaa8) leave [1]
    OP (0x27a402c) enter
    COP (0x27dcac8) nextstate
    BINOP (0x27dcb00) leaveloop
        LOOP (0x27dcb20) enterloop
        LISTOP (0x27dcb68) lineseq
            COP (0x27dcb88) nextstate
            UNOP (0x27dcbc0) entersub [5]          # entry point for foo
                UNOP (0x27dcbf4) null [148]
                    OP (0x27dcbdc) pushmark
                    LISTOP (0x27dcc48) substr [4]  # substr gets called here
                        OP (0x27dcc30) null [3]
                        SVOP (0x27dcc84) const [6] PV (0x2319944) "123"
                        SVOP (0x27dcc68) const [7] IV (0x2319904) 4
                        SVOP (0x27dcc14) const [8] IV (0x231944c) 6
                    UNOP (0x27dcca0) null [17]
                        PADOP (0x27dccf4) gv  GV (0x2318e5c) *foo
```

Is this optimizer behavior documented anywhere? `perlsub` only mentions inlining of constant functions. Given that the warning is being reported on the wrong line and that `no warnings` isn't working in the lexical scope where the call is being made I'm inclined to report this as a bug, although I can't think of how it could reasonably be fixed while preserving the optimization.

Note: This behavior was observed under Perl 5.16.1.

Comment: It's not inlined. `substr` returns a magical value that contains the operands passed to `substr` when it's called as an lvalue (e.g. as an argument to a sub). The substring operation happens when the magical value is accessed. This is done to allow `substr(...) = "abc";`

Comment: e.g. `perl -E'$_="abc"; my $r = \substr($_,0,1); $_="def"; say $$r;'` prints `d`

Comment: @ikegami: I think you hit on the real answer; please add your comment as one. I'm debating a doc patch; `@_` aliasing causing a `substr` call to be interpreted in lvalue context is subtle. I submitted [bug 123552](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123552) against the current behavior.

Comment: It's not a bug. // The docs already explicitly mention this situation, so I'm not sure what doc changes you want. // The list of a foreach loop and the arguments of a sub/method call are lvalues because Perl always passes by reference ("aliases"). e.g. `perl -E'for ($x) { $_ = "abc"; } say $x;'` and `perl -E'sub { $_[0] = "abc"; }->($x); say $x'`

Comment: @ikegami: The bug is that `no warnings 'substr'` has no effect in the lexical scope where the `substr` call which triggered it appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you saw from B::Terse, the `substr` is not inlined.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'f(substr($_, 3, 4))'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gvsv[*_] s
5  <$> const[IV 3] s
6  <$> const[IV 4] s
7  <@> substr[t4] sKM/3        <-- The substr operator is evaluated first.
8  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
9  <1> entersub[t5] vKS/TARG   <-- The sub call second.
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

When `substr` is called as an lvalue context, `substr` returns a magical scalar that contains the operands passed to `substr`.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$_ = "abcdef"; Dump(${\ substr($_, 3, 4) })'
SV = PVLV(0x2865d60) at 0x283fbd8
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)          <--- Gets and sets are magical.
  IV = 0                          GMG: A function that mods the scalar
  NV = 0                               is called before fetches.
  PV = 0                          SMG: A function is called after the
  MAGIC = 0x2856810                    scalar is modified.
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_substr
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_substr(x)
  TYPE = x
  TARGOFF = 3                      <--- substr's second arg
  TARGLEN = 4                      <--- substr's third arg
  TARG = 0x287bfd0                 <--- substr's first arg
  FLAGS = 0              
  SV = PV(0x28407f0) at 0x287bfd0  <--- A dump of substr's first arg
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
    PV = 0x2865d20 "abcdef"\0
    CUR = 6
    LEN = 10
    COW_REFCNT = 1
```

Subroutine arguments are evaluated in lvalue context because subroutine arguments are always passed by reference in Perl<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ perl -E'sub f { $_[0] = "def"; }  $x = "abc"; f($x); say $x;'
def
```

The substring operation happens when the magical scalar is accessed.

```
$ perl -E'$x = "abc"; $r = \substr($x, 0, 1); $x = "def"; say $$r;'
d
```

This is done to allow `substr(...) = "abc";`

---

1. This is probably documented using language similar to the following: "The elements of `@_` are aliased to the subroutine arguments."

Comment: *smacks head* I'm not sure why I was interpreting the `O` output as execution order instead of as a tree. I think I got off on the wrong foot due to the "substr outside of string" warning being reported as occurring on the `my $s = shift` line, rationalized that as meaning that the call to `substr` was in-lined there as some sort of obscure optimization to save call overhead, and never found my way back. *sigh*

Answer (score 8):

This is a documented behaviour (in [perldiag](http://p3rl.org/perldiag)):

> substr outside of string
>
> (W substr),(F) You tried to reference a substr() that pointed
>              outside of a string.  That is, the absolute value of the offset was
>              larger than the length of the string.  See "substr" in perlfunc.
>              This warning is fatal if substr is used in an lvalue context (as
>              the left hand side of an assignment **or as a subroutine argument** for
>              example).

Emphasis mine.

Changing the call to

```
foo(my $o = substr('123', 4, 6));
```

makes the warnings disappear.

Moving the `no warnings` into the sub doesn't change the behaviour for me. What Perl version do you have? (5.14.4 here).

The code I used for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1;

print 1, foo(my $s1 = substr('abc', 4, 6));
print 2, bar(my $s2 = substr('def', 4, 6));

{
    no warnings 'substr';
    print 3, foo(my $s3 = substr('ghi', 4, 6));
    print 4, bar(my $s4 = substr('jkl', 4, 6));
    print 5, bar(substr('mno', 4, 6)); # Stops here, reports line 12.
    print 6, foo(substr('pqr', 4, 6));
}
print "ok\n";

sub foo {
    my $s = shift;
}

sub bar {
    no warnings 'substr';
    my $s = shift;
}
```

### Update:

I'm getting the same behaviour in 5.10.1, but in 5.20.1, the behaviour is as you described.

Comment: Curious. I'm running 5.16.1; it isn't fatal there. Duplicating the call to `foo` results in two warnings.

Comment: @MichaelCarman: You're right. Tested in 5.20.1, it doesn't die and reports the warning inside the `foo`.

Comment: It looks like the behavior changed in 5.16. perl5160delta says *If the lvalue is only read from, not written to, it is now just a warning, as with rvalue `substr`.* Apparently perldiag wasn't updated to match. At any rate, the severity of the message is a tangent. The primary question is about the call to `substr` being inlined in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelCarman: They seem related, though, as the older versions report the warning at the correct line.

Comment: `"".substr(...)` would be simpler and easier than `my $temp = substr(...)`